# R Simmer - Using set_attribute and get_attribute and replication (using lapply)

Tags: r

I am trying to combine set_attribute and get_attribute replication (using lapply)
The following code without "get_attribute" runs well :

```
library(simmer)    

SystemTime <- 200
delay= c(20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200)/60
set.seed(1234)

elevators <- simmer()

worker <-
  trajectory("elevators service") %>% #trajectory name
  log_("new worker arrived") %>% #
  set_attribute("start_time", function() {now(elevators)}) %>%
  seize("elevator",amount = 1) %>% #elevator queue and service 
  timeout(function() sample(delay,1)) %>%
  release("elevator") 


elevators <-lapply(1:100, function(i) {
  simmer("elevators") %>%
  add_generator("worker", worker, function() exp(2)) %>% 
    add_resource("elevator",capacity = 2) %>% 
  run(until = SystemTime)

})
```

When I add  "get_attribute " like the following:

```
library(simmer) 

SystemTime <- 200
delay= c(20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200)/60
set.seed(1234)

elevators <- simmer()

worker <-
  trajectory("elevators service") %>% #trajectory name
  log_("new worker arrived") %>% #
  set_attribute("start_time", function() {now(elevators)}) %>%
  seize("elevator",amount = 1) %>% #elevator queue and service 
  timeout(function() sample(delay,1)) %>%
  log_(function() {paste("Waited: ", now(elevators) - get_attribute(elevators, "start_time"))}) %>%
  release("elevator") 


elevators <-lapply(1:100, function(i) {
  simmer("elevators") %>%
  add_generator("worker", worker, function() exp(2)) %>% 
    add_resource("elevator",capacity = 2) %>% 
  run(until = SystemTime)

})
```

I get the following error:

> Error in run_(private$sim_obj, until) :    Evaluation error: there is
>   no arrival running.

Seeking help on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Dor, I have made a few simple edits to your question. You have clearly taken time and effort in learning to post an SO question using the tools as a new user. Well done.  I hope you get the answer you seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example runs without error, but it's not working well actually. Basically, you have a scoping problem. The simulation environment must be in the scope of the trajectory, so that `get_attribute` (and `now`) can see it. The solution is to put everything inside the same function:

```
library(simmer) 

SystemTime <- 200
delay= c(20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200)/60
set.seed(1234)

elevators <-lapply(1:100, function(i) {
  elevator <- simmer("elevator")

  worker <-
    trajectory("elevator service") %>% #trajectory name
    log_("new worker arrived") %>% #
    set_attribute("start_time", function() {now(elevator)}) %>%
    seize("elevator",amount = 1) %>% #elevator queue and service 
    timeout(function() sample(delay,1)) %>%
    log_(function() {paste("Waited: ", now(elevator) - get_attribute(elevator, "start_time"))}) %>%
    release("elevator") 

  elevator %>%
    add_generator("worker", worker, function() rexp(1, 2)) %>% 
    add_resource("elevator", capacity = 2) %>% 
    run(until = SystemTime)
})
```

Also note that I replaced `exp(2)` with `rexp(1, 2)` in your generator, which I think that it's what you really wanted.

Comment: Hi thank you for your fast response, its was very useful .

Comment: Do you know how can i insert attribute values into data frame ?

Comment: for example how can i store for each replication the get_mon_resources(env) ?

Comment: About the attributes, set `mon=2` in `add_generator` for those you wish to save the attributes, and retrieve them with `get_mon_attributes`. About replications, `get_mon_resources`, as well as `get_mon_arrivals` and `get_mon_attributes`, works also for lists of simulation environments. So you can get them with `get_mon_resources(elevators)` in my previous response.

Comment: Thanks !, its working , but the statement  "function() {now(elevator)}" doesnt give me value.

Comment: I tested it and it does.